# Calculating Expected Value with Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, expected-value

A company has 100 employees. For a Christmas team-building exercise, they divide the 100 employees into 25 teams of 4.

Randomly and independently, they give an award to 20 employees.

--

Find the expected value of the number of awards given to the employees on any given team. What type of distribution is this?

So far, I have that there are 100!/(4!^25)*25! combinations for the teams, but don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 3):

Each employee expects $20/100=1/5$ of an award, so by linearity of expectation, each team of $4$ expects to get $4/5$ many awards.

Comment: thank you! I overthought that a little too much. If I wanted to find the expected value of the number of teams with 0 awards, is this correct: (.1)^0 * (.9) ^5 * 20?

Answer (score 1):

We have $n$ total people and $m$ with awards and the $n$ people put into groups of size $k$.  Since the awards are given uniformly and independently it is sufficient to look at the distribution of awards to first $k$ people.

To get $i$ award winners in the first $k$
- Select $i$ people among the $m$ award winners
- Select $k - i$ people among the $n - m$ award winners

The number of ways of doing that is

$${m \choose i} \cdot {n - m \choose k - i}$$.

The number of ways of choosing $k$ out of $n$ people is
$${n \choose k}$$.

So the probability of exactly $i$ out of $k$ people having the award is the ratio.

Comment: The question asks for expectation, not probabilities.

Comment: The question asked for how to think about the expectation **and** distribution.